# sounds not playing with mediaplayer after playing some sounds

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playing

I'm developing an android application which is collection of 100 sound effects.
After I play for instance 25 of the sounds, I can't play anymore and I have to close the application and wait for some minutes then open the application and now I can play other sounds.

```
final MediaPlayer mp81 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a81);
```

I play the sound using the below code:

```
mp81.start();
```

I stop the playing sound using the below code:

```
mp81.seekTo(0);
```

I also used `stop()` method but the problem were still existing.
is there any other method i have to add?

Comment: make sure you cleaning memory when you played one sound

Comment: just a suggestion, for this kind of task SoundPool class might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note: consider using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for playing short sounds.

Regarding your use-case: you initialize your `MediaPlayer` instance using the static `create()` method which means you create a new `MediaPlayer` object for each sound instead of reusing an existing instance and just changing the data source. This might negatively affect the performance of your app. I suggest that you create an array of paths to your sounds and then instantiate the `MediaPlayer` like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
     mp.setDataSource(yourArray[x]);
     mp.prepare();
     mp.start();
  } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Consult the [MediaPlayer Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for more information.

Comment: I followed what you said but unfortunately I'm still having the problem and the app also force closes soon

Comment: please post your updated code and LogCat messages that appear when your app crashes

Comment: this is the code i have written based on what you mentioned above. the problem is that when running the application no sound is played and the logcat says: setDataSource called in state 8 look at my code in the answer section below....

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.a1);
if (i[0] == false)
                {try {mp.setDataSource(source[0].toString());mp.start();}
                    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_button);
i[0] = true;}else{mp.stop();
b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.horn);
i[0] = false;}}});

Comment: try to initialize the MediaPlayer using new and then calling prepare() or prepareAsync(). And I strongly recommend you to consult the API documentation I linked, MediaPlayer is trickier than it may seem